# How to solve $y + |y| = \cdots$

Tags: absolute-value

I want to calculate the equipotential lines for $f(x, y) = x + y + |x| + |y|$. The domain is $ℝ^2$ and range $[0, \infty)$. I started like this:

$$
x + y + |x| + |y| = c \ge 0 \\
y + |y| = c - x - |x|
$$

But I can't continue any further, I don't know how to get rid of the $|y|$. How can I solve the last equation by $y$?

Comment: We have that for non-negative values $|v| + v = 2v$ and for negative values of $v$, we have that $|v| + v = 0$. Split into cases.

Comment: Solve separately the four cases $$x\ge0\wedge y\ge0\\x<0\wedge y\ge 0\\x\ge0\wedge y<0\\ x<0\wedge y<0$$ and see the simplifications.

Comment: Consider the function $f(y)=y+|y|$.  On positive real numbers it simplifies and is obviously injective, but on non-positive real numbers it is not injective.  Indeed it simplifies there to a constant.